# Apache Storm: InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [x] subscribes from non-existent component [y]

Tags: java, apache-storm

I've used the code from [this blog](http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2014/02/helloworld-apache-storm-word-counter.html) (which works fine):

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", new LineReaderSpout());
builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter");

LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("HelloStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
```

But when I tweak it to have two spouts which read lines, send the lines to two `word-spitter` bolts and finally send the results to a single `word-counter` bolt, the exception of an invalid topology is thrown.

My tweaked code

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", new LineReaderSpout());
builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout2", new LineReaderSpout());        
builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
builder.setBolt("word-spitter2", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout2");
builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt(),2).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter").shuffleGrouping("word-splitter2");
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("HelloStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
```

What is wrong about the topology? I don't see any improper flow. How can `word-spitter2` be non existent when it is actually created?

> 6661 [main] INFO  b.s.d.nimbus - [req 1] Access from:  principal:
>   op:submitTopology 6718 [main] WARN  b.s.d.nimbus - Topology submission
>   exception. (topology name='HelloStorm') #InvalidTopologyException
>   InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [word-counter] subscribes from
>   non-existent component [word-splitter2]) 6721 [main] ERROR
>   o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
>   backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:160)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:299)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__6583$exec_fn__1236__auto__$reify__6598.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:1091)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__6583$exec_fn__1236__auto__$reify__6598.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:1119)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_73]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_73]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_73]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_73]     at
>   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
>   ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]    at
>   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
>   ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]    at
>   backtype.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:276)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:43)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   backtype.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source)
>   ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]   at
>   com.spnotes.storm.HelloStorm.main(HelloStorm.java:36) ~[classes/:?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got typo - sp**l**itter2.

builder.setBolt("**word-spitter2**", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout2");
builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt(),2).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter").shuffleGrouping("**word-splitter2**");